# Regular expression of: $\{ w \in \Sigma^* : w \text{ does not contain the substring 110} \}$.

Tags: regular-expressions

Given $\Sigma = \{ 0,1,2 \}$, write a regular expression for $$\{ w \in \Sigma^* : w \text{ does not contain the substring 110} \}\;.$$

I know how to do a regular expression for a language that does not contain a substring of two consequent characters, but here it is three and I've been trying alot. Any direction would help!

Comment: It’s $\Sigma$ that’s $\{0,1,2\}$, not $\Sigma^*$. What regular expression would you write for the language over $\Sigma$ of words that don’t contain the substring $10$?

Comment: Sorry,edited. Trying to think of such a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is

> $\bigl((\epsilon + 1 + 11)(0 + 2)\bigr)^*(\epsilon + 1 + 11)$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2139676) for more details on how this expression was obtained.