# Complements in regular expressions

Tags: computer-science, regular-expressions

Come up with a regular expression for the following language
$$
\{w \mid w \text{ doesn’t contain the substring } 110\} 
$$
The book provides a more complex answer, but I think that using the complement is easier. Do you think this works?:
$\Sigma^*-\Sigma^*110\Sigma^*$

Comment: subtraction is not defined. see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_the‌​ory

Comment: @dave I think the author wanted to express this in terms of set difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression of the language as the complement of the language $\Sigma^*110\Sigma^*$ is correct. However, it does not give a regular expression for the language. A regular expression can only use letters, union, product and star operator (and the complement is not allowed). The fact that the complement of a language $L$ given by a regular expression can also be expressed by a regular expression is a nontrivial result, due to Kleene. The standard three step algorithm to find a regular expression for the complement of $L$ is the following:

**Step 1**. Find a deterministic complete automaton $\mathcal{A}$ accepting $L$.

**Step 2**. Find a deterministic automaton $\mathcal{B}$ accepting the complement $L$. This is the easy step: it suffices to modify $\mathcal{A}$ by replacing its set of final states by its complement.

**Step 3**. Convert the automaton $\mathcal{B}$ into a regular expression.